# Suppose $X_n /a $ converges to standard normal in distribution. How to say normally that $X_n$ converges to normal $n(0, a^2)$?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $X_n /a $ converges to standard normal in distribution. How to say formally that $X_n$ converges to normal $n(0, a^2)$ in distribution? Slutsky's theorem? I need a formal statement. Thanks!

My question is from Casella & Berger exercise 5.44.

Let $X_i,i=1,2,...,$ be independent Bernoulli(p) random variables and let $Y_n= \frac{1}{n}\Sigma_{i=1}^n X_i$.

Show that $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-p) \rightarrow n[0,p(1-p)]$ in distribution.

This question is not difficult for me. Since they are iid, thus they satisfy Lindeberg condition and qualify for using central limit theorem.

$E(Y_n)=p$ and $Var(Y_n)=\frac{1}{n} p(1-p)$, thus $\frac{\sqrt{n} (Y_n-p) }{\sqrt{p(1-p)}} \rightarrow n(0,1)$ in distribution.

Now the last step and also my question is how to say $\sqrt{n}(Y_n-p) \rightarrow n[0,p(1-p)]$ in distribution? The solution I found in website is saying this step needs Slutsky's theorem.

Comment: What do you mean by "a formal statement"? A proof?

Comment: No theorem. Do you know how to write  the distribution of $X_n/a$ in terms of the distribution of $X_n$ ?

Comment: If $a$ is a constant rather than something affected by $n$ then this is a simple [scale transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family)

Comment: I make some more edits in the question. Thanks!